# Grails filters not being called for custom actions

Tags: grails, filter, grails-filters

I'm trying to implement a  filter that should be called in certain instances before going to a GSP page. As the URL does not differ a lot between the instances where I want it to happen, and those where I don't, I thought the best way to do this would be to create a method that does nothing (with a print statement inside) - but can simply be called when I want the filter action to take place.

I have tried this as both:

```
def hello(){
    print "hello"       
}
```

and

```
def hello = {
    print "hello"
}
```

calling these simply by adding

```
hello()
```

at the relevant point

The start of my filter is as follows:

```
import uui.FormattingService

class TimeFormatterFilters {

    def FormattingService formattingService

    def filters = {
        someFilter(controller: 'userProfile', action: 'hello') {
            before = {
                print "filter action taking place"
```

I do not see the print statement from within the filter for either of the newly made methods within the UserProfileController, yet if I swap the action for the filter to `'index'`, I see the print within the filter being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are calling the `hello()` action directly from another action within your controller. This is just a normal method call and does not pass through the filter.

Grails filters are called when an HTTP client requests a specific URI e.g. `http://localhost:8080/my-app/myController/myAction` will match `myController` and `myAction`.

If you simply call `myAction()` from within the controller when responding to a different URI the filter won't be used. Which is what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise a HTTP call had to be made. It seems using a beforeInterceptor instead would do the trick?

Comment: The beforeInterceptor is also going to be based on what action is being called by the HTTP request. Just like a filter.

Answer (score 0):

you said this :

> calling these simply by adding
>
> hello()

Does this mean that you are calling the hello() method from another method ? Make sure that in order to test filters you need to hit the URL directly /userProfile/home

Comment: Yes, I mean I'm calling the hello() method from another.
I'm not sure I understand your second point - where has home come from?

Comment: calling `hello()` from another method does not invoke the filter. That's just a method call. The filter is invoked via a web request.